# Relevancy of links in "Sponsored links for this tag"

Tags: discussion, questions, search, tag-search

When I hit my bookmark to find new questions, there's always this *Sponsored links for this tag* (`.everyoneloves__tag-sponsorship`) box.

[image]

and the usefulness of some of the links in that box are questionable.

As we all know sponsored content is important when it comes to income. But users actually clicking those links also matters.

For an example, why would an Android developer click on the link `Download Android Studio` repeatedly? So showing that link to an Android developer each and every time is pretty useless.

I think it would be great to come up with a solution to show either useful links or to remove those useless links.

Comment: How does the system know an visitor is an Android developer? Keep in mind those links are paid for by an advertiser. I assume they have marketeers that decide what is useful or not. What would you suggest to make them useful? Remove them if you clicked on any of one?

Comment: They reside to promote certain things. Just like if you see some StackOverflow ads.  You won't say that "remove this, I'm already on StackOverflow". Their job is to promote.

Comment: @rene One way to find is using the user's rep for relevant tags ie `android`

Comment: I'm not saying that we should remove the banner completely, I'm telling by making it more relevant to the developer there's a better chance that user may click on those links thus generating more revenue. SO can ask the advertises to give more links...

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala do you think the Google marketeers want to pay for that feature to be implemented? Sounds extremely performance intensive and not very well cache-able  for only little gain.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble reproducing this, even in an incognito browser.

> As we all know sponsored content is important when it comes to income.
>   But users actually clicking those links also matters.

Well we don't know how much of the marketing is people clicking the links or just seeing the links.

> For an example, why would an Android developer click on the link
>   Download Android Studio repeatedly? So showing that link to an Android
>   developer each and every time is pretty useless.

There would be plenty of people cruising the site, new to Android without a drop of knowledge how to program in it. I was one of these and taught myself from the docs and by answering questions on here.(and developing apps)

I'm sure Google has a pretty good idea of who their target market is. They are highly skilled at obtaining and analysing big data.

> I think it would be great to come up with a solution to show either
>   useful links or to remove those useless links.

Well you can just ignore the banner and read down the posts. It's like someone setting down a vacuum cleaner in the middle of the living room floor. After a while it can become habitual to step over it without noticing it.